# How to edit a table row using angluarJS?

Tags: angularjs, html

I'm searching for a solution to edit in-line table rows. Pretty much like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/benfosterdev/UWLFJ/), but with populated comboboxes too.

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.model = {
        contacts: [{
            id: 1,
            name: "Ben",
            age: 28
        }, {
            id: 2,
            name: "Sally",
            age: 24
        }, {
            id: 3,
            name: "John",
            age: 32
        }, {
            id: 4,
            name: "Jane",
            age: 40
        }],
        selected: {}
    };

    // gets the template to ng-include for a table row / item
    $scope.getTemplate = function (contact) {
        if (contact.id === $scope.model.selected.id) return 'edit';
        else return 'display';
    };

    $scope.editContact = function (contact) {
        $scope.model.selected = angular.copy(contact);
    };

    $scope.saveContact = function (idx) {
        console.log("Saving contact");
        $scope.model.contacts[idx] = angular.copy($scope.model.selected);
        $scope.reset();
    };

    $scope.reset = function () {
        $scope.model.selected = {};
    };
});
```

How can I make inline editable comboboxes ? Each line should have a name, age and a group of options.

Comment: I cannot get what you want. Comboboxes with names?

Comment: With anything, atm I have a name and age fields for each line of table. The point is to have a combobox too, with anything, could be an array of values.

Comment: so you want to show dropdown input list `<select>`? that is it?

Comment: I just cannot get what is the problem. Why you cannot show `<select>`  instead of `<input>`? What is obstacle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier, and I would venture to say nicer, if you use ng-grid instead of html tables. The grid has built-in editing, and you can customize the kind of editor, such that your cell could display as plain text, but use a combo box for editing.

Here is a plunker that shows an editable combo box on the Gender column:
http://plnkr.co/edit/zsxqZNQCnpFySjSWcf1D?p=preview

```
{field:'gender', displayName: 'Gender', enableCellEdit: true,editableCellTemplate: '<span id="gender"><select ng-class="\'colt\' + col.index" + ng-input="COL_FIELD" ng-model="COL_FIELD" ng-options="c.value as c.name for c in genders"></select></span>'}]
```

And here is the documentation for ng-grid:
http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/